# Two alert views in same view controller

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I have two `UIAlertView`s in same view controller and I want to use the delegate method

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *）alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger) buttonIndex
```

This method will get called when a button in an alert view is pressed. However both alert views will call the same method.

How can I different the two alert views?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the `tag` property to different values when you display the alert. It's just an integer and can be queried in the callback/delegate method.

Here's an example (using an ActionSheet rather than an AlertView, but the principle is exactly the same):

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"
                                                         delegate:self
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                           destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                otherButtonTitles:@"Some option", nil];
actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleDefault;
actionSheet.tag = 10;
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
[actionSheet release];
```

Then in your selector:

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
  switch (actionSheet.tag) {
    case 10:
      // do stuff
      break;
    case 20:
      // do other stuff
      break;
  }
}
```

Of course, you'd use constants rather than literal values, localised strings, etc, but that's the basic idea.

Comment: i understand ur meaning it jus like set the button tag value,but i dont see alert view have a property is tag, can please show the code in details

Comment: tag is a property of UIView, of which UIAlertView (and, for that matter, UIButton) is a subclass, so it does have it.

Comment: I've been using an iVar for this, which after reading your answer, was silly!  Thanks.